# What is wrong with this linked list implementation?

Tags: python, singly-linked-list, attributeerror

Running the script produces the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/GeeksforGeeks/Linked List/Insertion of Nodes in LinkedList.py", line 49, in <module>

llist.printList()
  File "D:/PycharmProjects/GeeksforGeeks/Linked List/Insertion of Nodes in LinkedList.py", line 39, in printList
```

The offending line is:

```
print(temp.data,end=' ')
```

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'data'

## My Code is:-

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def push(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def insertAfter(self,prev_node,new_data):
        if prev_node is None:
            return

        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_node

    def append(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        last = self.head
        while (last.next):
            last = last.next

        last.next = new_data

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp):
            print(temp.data,end=' ')
            temp = temp.next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.append(6)
    llist.push(7)
    llist.push(1)
    llist.append(4)
    llist.insertAfter(llist.head.next,8)
    llist.printList()
```

Comment: Last line in "append": "last.next = new_data"

Comment: You're making the `next` link in the last node point to the data instead of the node containing the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in the `append` function:

```py
    def append(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        last = self.head
        while last.next:
            last = last.next

        last.next = new_node # should not be new_data
```

Answer (score 1):

In your method `append`, `last.next` should be `new_node`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def push(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = self.head
        self.head = new_node

    def insertAfter(self,prev_node,new_data):
        if prev_node is None:
            return

        new_node = Node(new_data)
        new_node.next = prev_node.next
        prev_node.next = new_node

    def append(self,new_data):
        new_node = Node(new_data)

        if self.head is None:
            self.head = new_node
            return

        last = self.head
        while (last.next):
            last = last.next

        last.next = new_node

    def printList(self):
        temp = self.head
        while (temp):
            print(temp.data,end=' ')
            temp = temp.next

if __name__ == '__main__':
    llist = LinkedList()
    llist.append(6)
    llist.push(7)
    llist.push(1)
    llist.append(4)
    llist.insertAfter(llist.head.next,8)
    llist.printList()
```

Output:

```
1 7 8 6 4
```